# Select elements if a particular sibling is present with a particular child node

Tags: xml, xpath

i am trying to select all keys which have a next sibling node **dict** and whose one of it's child nodes is **true**, for example in the below xml :

```
<dict>
    <key>A</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>B</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>C</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>D</key>
    <id>1</id>
</dict>
```

I should get A and C. I have tried:

```
//key[../dict/true]
//key[../dict/[following-sibling::dict/true]]
```

and many others. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this:

```
//key[following-sibling::dict[position()=1]/true]
```

This selects the following `dict` elements that have a `position()` of 1 (meaning immediately following the `key` as well as a descendant of `true`.

`following-sibling::node()` selects **ALL** the following siblings, but `following-sibling::node()[position()=1]` selects only the **FIRST** one.

Comment: Actually, your path expression will also select `key` elements that do **not** have an immediate next sibling named `dict` - because `following-sibling::dict[position()=1]` means "the first `dict` element after the current context node", not the first following sibling in general.

Comment: nah , the xpath is not returning me any result.

Comment: @orange, not sure about your environment, but with your xml example, my xpath does return the expected results.

Comment: @orange No, this expression is certainly correct - either you are doing something wrong or the input document is not the one you have shown us.

Comment: @MathiasMüller yes, you are correct.  Using `node()` or `*` is ensuring the `dict` node is immediately following.

Comment: i am trying the xpath on http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester and none of the queries has worked ...let me try with some other tool

Comment: @orange Yes, you need a better tool, both answers produce the correct result for your input.  I recommend XMLSpy if you're doing a lot of XML work.

Comment: @orange If you need a reliable tool to only occasionally work with, use http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php. It's a sound XPath 1.0 engine.

Comment: Mathias Müller : million thanks for the xpath tool link too. i tried  few more sites without success . Yes all the queries are working !! thanks very much steve . i am moving the query into nokogiri(ruby). pretty hairy queries too, guess have to put some time  understand them now !! thanks very much again

Comment: yes the query is working in nokogiri alright ! wot's with few of these online tools , they can't find a good open source standards compliant xpath library to use ?? i could have easily spent few more hours pulling my hair out if you guys didn't come to the rescue :)

Answer (score 2):

The path expression you need is

```
/dict/key[following-sibling::*[position() = 1 and name() = 'dict' and true]]
```

which translates to

```
/dict/key                Select an outermost element, and its children `key`
[following-sibling::*    but only if there is a following sibling
[position() = 1          that is the first following sibling
and name() = 'dict'      and that is also a `dict` element
and true]]               that has at least one child element named `true`.
```

Taking as input the document you show, the results are (individual results separated by `----------`):

```
<key>A</key>
-----------------------
<key>C</key>
```

Alternatively:

```
/dict/key[following-sibling::*[position() = 1 and self::dict and true]]
```